# How standard containers allocates memory for their nodes (internal structures)?

Tags: c++

I cannot figure out how std::set and std::map, for example allocate the memory for their nodes if they have allocators of type

```
std::allocator<Key>
```

and

```
std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
```

respectively. As far as I can guess, there should be a code like this, in std::set, for example:

```
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& value)
{
    ...
    Node * node = new Node();
    node->value = value;
    ...
    return InsertNode(node);
 }
```

or

```
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& value)
{
    ...
    Node * node = new Node();
    node->p_value = a1.allocate(1);
    *(node->p_value) = value;
    ...
    return InsertNode(node);
 }
```

where Node is some internal structure like red-black tree node, for example.

So the question is how is this Node memory allocated?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your question is – what about the memory allocation process is not clear to you? As the answers explained, `allocator::allocate` is called at some point, which calls `operator new`, which does a `malloc`. Are you wondering what happens before the `allocate()` or with its return value or are you asking how `malloc()` does its job?

Comment: @Chronial I am not asking how std::allocator is implemented, but how std::set is implemented. How it uses the allocator to allocate both Key and Node while allocator::allocate() return type is Key*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The allocator that you provide is rebound to the type of the node structure, and then used to allocate the nodes.

`std::allocator` (the default) will call `operator new`, which then will do something implementation-specific (usually calling `malloc`).

Comment: How are they 'rebound'? What allocator methods are used for that?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator . Roughly, the container rebinds the allocator like `using NodeAllocator = typename Allocator::template rebind<InternalNodeType>`, which is constructible from the original allocator (as per the required valid expression `A a(b)`). So they can just convert it: `NodeAllocator nodeAllocator(allocator);`

Comment: Could you clarity please, does std::set allow the client to provide the instance of NodeAllocator like it does with Allocator allowing to pass its instance as the constructor argument?

Comment: Probably NodeAllocator is created like this NodeAllocator nodeAlloc(alloc); where alloc is Allocator instance.

Answer (score 6):

Allocators in C++ (for some reason) are expected to be typed. That is, a specific allocator class instance allocates objects of a specific type.

However, because the actual type a container may need to allocate can be different from the container's value type (the type the container logically contains), allocators are (mostly) required to be able to be converted into an alternate allocator instance that allocates objects of any other type. This process is called "rebinding", and it is initiated by invoking `allocator.rebind<U>`, where `U` is the type the system wants to actually allocate.

A new allocator instance which is a rebound form of the original allocator must allocate from the same memory pool as the original allocator. Rebinding is therefore treated as a type-based change, not a truly distinct object.

Implementations of standard library containers are not permitted to use `new` or `delete`; all of their dynamic de/allocation and object creation/destruction within allocated memory must be performed through the allocator.

When `std::set<T>` goes to insert an item, it will rebind your allocator to some node-type which internally contains either a `T` itself or enough properly aligned storage to create a `T` within. It will then use the allocator's interface to create that node type and initialize the `T` it contains. `std::map` is a bit more complicated, but essentially its node type must store a `Key` and a `Value`.

Comment: `allocator.rebind<U>` is deprecated in C++17, now there is `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<T>`

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Why cannot use `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::rebind_alloc<T>`? Is the `template` necessary?

Comment: @zjyhjqs: Yes, the `template` is necessary. The compiler needs to know if the dependent name `rebind_alloc` is a template. After all, the compiler doesn't know if it should interpret the `<` as a "less than" or "starting bracket of a template argument list". And yes, `< 0` could be a valid template argument *or* expression.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm still confused about why the `template` is concatenated behind `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>`? I haven't seen such syntax before, could you give me some references or even some keywords about it. Thanks.

Comment: @NicolBolas And also I wonder how to use it. For instance, I have a tree node type `TreeNode<T>` for type `T`, and an allocator `allocator<T>`. Should I write `std::allocator_traits<allocator<T>>::template rebind_traits<TreeNode<T>>`?